# Problemas con las fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Seguramente, sea solo cosas de novato, pero cuando intento enviar una fecha a un campo de una base de datos, me aparece toda la información tal que así:

```
Fri Oct 11 2019 00:29:05 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
```

Sí yo solo quiero una fecha de tipo `11-08-2019` ¿porqué me aparece toda esta información? La envío con una variable:

```
$fecha = Date("d m Y");
```

---

muy agracedido por las respuestas, pero no han funcionado.... 
seguramente no me he explicado bien...

necesito pasar a String una fecha....

si lo pongo de esta forma:
    $fecha=Date("Y-m-d"); 
me aparece toda la info:

```
Fri Oct 11 2019 00:23:54 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
```

si `$fecha="01-10-2019"`, todo va perfectamente

por lo que deduzco que `$fecha=Date("Y-m-d");`no genera un formato válido para enviarlo a un campo Texto.

Estoy utilizando MysqlPHPGenerator de SQLMaestro, y el siguiente codigo, vá en un evento que ocurre cuando editas un campo .La accion que debería ocurrir es que al cambiar el estado de un checkbox, me ponga la fecha en una columna tipo texto. nada mas... solo eso... pero me tiene mu quemaooo.....
La verdad es que la parte del 'ELSE' lo hace muy bien...

```
//$fecha="03-12-2018";
$fecha=Date("Y-m-d"); 

  if (sender.getValue() == "1")
  {
    editors['FechaFinal'].setValue($fecha)
    $('#FechaFinal').next().show();      

  }else {
  editors['FechaFinal'].setValue("Pendiente")
    $('#FechaFinal').next().show(); 
  }
```

Perdonad el tostón, pero no doy pá mas.....

Gracias...

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que hacer es declarar la columna del tipo `DATETIME` en la base de datos, y segundo, debes mandar la fecha formateada en `añomesdia` porque es así como las maneja la base de datos.

Comment: La columna es de tipo Date, y lo otro, voy a probarlo.... gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba darle el formato completo:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$lafechahoy = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");
```

Si tienes un campo de tipo DATE en la Base de datos, el formato con el que se debe insertar es "2019-10-11", intenta guardar la fecha como esta variable e insertala en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con

```
  $fecha=Date("Y-m-d");
```

asi tiene el formato de la columna de tipo DATE